# Incompatible block pointer types sending 'void (^__strong)(__strong id)' to parameter of type 'swizzleBlock' (aka 'void (^)(void)')

Tags: objective-c

Trying to fix issues with FBSDKEventBindingManager.m error for few days but still having hard time to find solution.

Error:

> Incompatible block pointer types sending 'void (^__strong)(__strong id)' to parameter of type 'swizzleBlock' (aka 'void (^)(void)')

Error in this line => `withBlock:blockToSuperview named:@"map_control"];`

```
void (^blockToSuperview)(id view) = ^(id view) {
    [self matchView:view delegate:nil];
};

void (^blockToWindow)(id view) = ^(id view) {
    [self matchView:view delegate:nil];
};


[FBSDKSwizzler swizzleSelector:@selector(didMoveToSuperview) 
                       onClass:[UIControl class]
                     withBlock:blockToSuperview named:@"map_control"];

[FBSDKSwizzler swizzleSelector:@selector(didMoveToWindow)
                       onClass:[UIControl class]
                     withBlock:blockToWindow named:@"map_control"];
```

Comment: add code what you have for blockToSuperview and blockToSuperview to better understand it.

Comment: Hi Bhavin, here's the reference from line 126 to line 140: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/master/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/Internal/AppEvents/Codeless/FBSDKEventBindingManager.m

Comment: Hi Bhavin, just updated the reference for blockToSuperview, hope this will help. Really struggling this past few days. Appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: You've probably got a mismatch either in nullability or in the ARC strong/weak/unretained specifiers between your blocks and the ones specified by the SDK. Try explicitly typing the blocks as `swizzleBlock` by doing something like: `swizzleBlock blockToSuperview = ^(id view) { ... }`.

Comment: @LichardBaliuag checkout my answer, that is what I understood from the reference you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is where FBSDK using typedef for swizzleBlock

```
typedef void (^swizzleBlock)();
```

This can be explained like

`typedef void (^swizzleBlock)(void); //void (^)(void) format`

Line 24 [here](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/cd14706204c47164dcebe03fb46100da0c6550eb/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/Internal/FBSDKSwizzler.h):

And the parameter being passed is of type

```
void (^blockToSuperview)(id view) = ^(id view) // void (^__strong)(__strong id)'
```

Which leads to type mismatch and showing you error

> Incompatible block pointer types sending 'void (^__strong)(__strong id)' to parameter of type 'swizzleBlock' (aka 'void (^)(void)')

Refer [this](http://fuckingblocksyntax.com/), it will helps you to understand the Objective-C block syntax at various points.

You should update the typedef to match the passing block.

```
typedef void (^swizzleBlock)(id);
```

Fixing, this will fix the error at a point, but in the same file there are many other types of block with different format, e.g tableViewBlock(line 185), collectionViewBlock(line 200) [checkout here](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/master/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/Internal/AppEvents/Codeless/FBSDKEventBindingManager.m). so, you will have to look for some generic workaround to fix it.

Hope it helps.